LVDS 30 pin cable matching
I have an LCD screen with a 30 pin LVDS connector. I have attached a table with the correct pin assignments, however I am unsure of how to match up the cables. LCD model: G150XVN01
There are only 24 wires coming from the sleeve, with 23 going into a 30 pin connector which plugs into the back of the display and the 24th being the only black wire is taped down the side. The 24 wires connect back into two sets of LVDS cables in the image attached. Looking at the back of the display, 30 pin is on the left and 1 is on right.
The wires are marked with either 1, 2 or 3 black or red marks.
6x Yellow wire: 1 red, 2 red, 3 red, 1 black, 2 black, 3 black
6x Orange wire: 1 red, 2 red, 3 red, 1 black, 2 black, 3 black
3x Grey Wire: 1 black, 1 red , 2 red
4x Pink: 1 red, 2 red, 1 black, 2 black
4x White wire: 1 red, 2 red, 1 black, 2 black




Max D Corbett - Hi, Where did the copied image (datasheet?) come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add each webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].) TY
